# gspread - get_all_values() returns an empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, gspread

If I call a sheet by name, get_all_values function will always give me an empty list for a sheet that is definitely not empty.

```
import gspread

sheet = workbook.worksheet(sheet_name)
all_rows_list = sheet.get_all_values()
```

The only time get_all_values seems to return like it should is if I do the following:

```
all_rows_list = workbook.sheet1.get_all_values()
```

But the above works just for the first sheet and for no other, which is kind of useless for a workbook with more sheets.

What always works is reading row by row like

```
one_row_list = sheet.row_values(1) # first row
```

But the problem is that I'm trying to read a relatively big workbook with lots of sheets to figure out where I'm supposed to start writing, and it looks like reading row by row triggers "RESOURCES EXHAUSTED" error very fast.

So, am I doing something wrong or is get_all_values broken in gspread?

**EDIT:**
Added a screenshot.[image]

Comment: What's the value of `sheet_name`? Do you really get different results by calling `get_all_values()` on the same sheet obtained via `.sheet1` and `.worksheet(sheet_name)`?? As `get_all_values` [is quite simple](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/50c5d888bd1f8ba1d2800bdfa7cf6cd785852c24/gspread/models.py#L580) I'd compare the `title` of the sheet in the two cases. // Do you use Python 3 and the latest version of gspread?

Comment: sheet_name is a string. I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything right. I edited my question and added a screenshot. You can see that row_values returns normally, but get_all_values doesn't and get_all_records returns an error. I'm using Python 3 and I installed gspread yesterday, so it should be the latest version.

Comment: In my environment, I couldn't replicate your situation. So I would like to propose other method. gspread can directly use Sheets API. Using this, how about using spreadsheets.values.get? The method is [`values_get`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_get). And the sample script is this. `print(client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId).values_get(sheetName))` At first, please set `spreadsheetId` and `sheetName`. If this also didn't work for your situation, I apologize. At that time, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue?

Comment: Doesn't work. First sheet returns fine, but others are missing "values" key. https://i.ibb.co/0hH1W62/first-sheet.png  https://i.ibb.co/f03FH0w/any-other-sheet.png

Comment: Maybe it could have something to do with scopes? Before I added auth/drive scope, I couldn't even get a list of sheets or anything. https://i.ibb.co/QFL4zd9/scopes.png

Comment: The `get_all_records()` error is a bug exposed by get_all_values() returning an empty list ([fixed in the dev version](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/commit/1580376c6509d9e919973e84903aa50c5ab1a525)). `row_values(1)` [makes](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/50c5d888bd1f8ba1d2800bdfa7cf6cd785852c24/gspread/models.py#L663) a request with `X101!A1:1` as the range, while `get_all_values` [requests](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/50c5d888bd1f8ba1d2800bdfa7cf6cd785852c24/gspread/models.py#L588) a `X101` range. Perhaps it's getting confused for a cell reference?

Comment: OK, I guess I managed to do what I was looking for with something like ws.range("A1:C"+str(end_row)). That end_row is usually row_count of the sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed your replying just now. I apologize for this. The method of `values_get` directly use Sheets API. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, for example, how about `print(client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId).values_get("'X101'"))`?

Comment: No need to apologize. I found a solution that might be even better than to get an entire sheet, since I just need first 3 columns in the sheet. If you want to recreate this, it seems like you can just by creating sheets with names like "X101", "X102" etc., since it might be a problem with names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gspread` doesn't work well with sheets with names that could be confused as a cell reference in the A1 notation (like `X101` and `AT8` in your case).

https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/554 is an older issue that describes the underlying problem (the symptoms in that issue are different, but I'm pretty sure the root problem is the same).

I'll copy the workaround with [providing a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57796269/gspread-get-all-values-returns-an-empty-list#comment102042398_57796269), that you've discovered yourself:

> `ws.range("A1:C"+str(end_row))` That `end_row` is usually `row_count` of the sheet.